# Where vs AND in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I normally don't use an `AND` in the same line as `ON` when performing a `LEFT JOIN`, as I have faced issues in the past. I rather prefer to not go into this pickle and instead put any additional condition in a `WHERE` clause, which is reliable. But today, out of curiousity, I would love to put this question forward and be clear once and for all.

**Question**: What really goes on when in a `LEFT JOIN` when I use the "exta" conditions? Why doesn't it behave in the same manner as `WHERE`?

**SAMPLE QUERIES**

```
create table #a
(
id int,
name varchar(3)
)


create table #b
(
id int,
name varchar(3)
)

insert into #a
select 1, 'abc'
union
select 2, 'def'
union
select 3, 'ghi'


insert into #b
select 1, 'abc'
union
select 2, 'def'

select * from #a a left join #b b on a.id = b.id 
where a.id = 3

select * from #a a left join #b b on a.id = b.id 
and a.id = 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This version filters on `a.id`:

```
select *
from #a a left join
     #b b
     on a.id = b.id 
where a.id = 3
```

This version does not filter on `a.id`:

```
select *
from #a a left join
     #b b
     on a.id = b.id and a.id = 3;
```

Why not?  Go to the definition of the `left join`.  It takes all rows from the first table, regardless of whether the `on` clause evaluates to true, false, or `NULL`.  So, filters on the first table have no impact in a `left join`.

Filters on the first table should be in the `where` clause.  Filters on the second table should be in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can put conditions on the "right tables" columns in the ON clause.

Comment: The condition is on the left table.

Comment: It was a general answer, perhaps not suitable for the sample queries.